# Good compression strategy for line-orientated input on stdin

Tags: text, command-line, compression, pipe

I have an very large text file of data: several billion lines which are mostly of the form:

```
On tick 112 total blocks 120
```

A simple Perl script turns this into comma separated values i.e., in this case:

```
112,120
```

I'd like to compress the Perl output on the fly but the obvious approaches eg

```
perl myscript.pl myinputfile.txt | bzip2 > compressedoutput.bz2
```

don't seem to compress the output at all (presumably because this can't be done one line at a time?)

Is there a way round this? Obviously I can generate the output file and then compress it, but I wonder is there a single command line way of getting good results?

Comment: many Qs here on S.O. deal with `unbuffer` and the perl solutions to the same problem, so look around a little for those terms. I would also confirm that compressing the seperate file does reduce the size. Given the nature of your data, that may be difficult to do. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how the writes are done to the pipe. The bytes are compressed the same on the other end of the pipe no matter what.

If you have correctly described your data, consisting of nothing but decimal digits, commas, and newlines, then it should definitely compress by more than a factor of two.

What exactly are you seeing?

By the way, you can and should further encode the decimal character integers to binary integers.

Comment: I want to use the output with R on a different machine, so using binary digits not a good option. The output is the same as the input -ie no compression at all

Comment: You could convert it back on the other end. Converting to binary is just another form of compression. The output of a compressor is arbitrary binary bytes.